# xampp mysql folder is readonly and can't remove read only attribute

Tags: mysql, xampp

After installing XAMPP. The Apache server works fine but MySQL not working. The log file shows that ibdata1 must be writable. Below log message.

```
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2021-07-29 15:00:52 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Then I check MySQL folder and I found it read-only and I can't change it.
Any help

Comment: which operating system are you using and maybe you are a better fit on superuser

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: in your my.ini file is the location for data usually  `datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data" 
when you right click on the folder change teh permission see https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/#accessing